# ConfigureKestrel with SSL cert from Key Vault

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, ssl

I am getting the below exception when I try to add my SSL cert from KeyVault

```
System.NotSupportedException: The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.
```

I generated my ssl cert.pfx from my GoDaddy SSL cert using OpenSSL

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out "MyCert.pfx" -inkey "myPrivateKey.pem" -in "MyPem.pem"
```

From there I added the .pfx to the Key Vault certificate store.

In my Program.cs I configure Kesteral becuase I am running in a docker container on Linux App Service

```
.ConfigureKestrel(async (context, options) =>
{
    var certificateClient = new CertificateClient(_uri, _azureCredential);

    KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy certificate = await certificateClient.GetCertificateAsync(certName);

    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificate.Cer);

    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 443, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps(certificate);
    });
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The PEM file is text.  Open with a text editor and see what labels are in the file.  The encryption mode and private key are not compatible.

Comment: IS the certificate field "haskey" is true?

Comment: @QiangFu I dont see a haskey field, however, the HasPrivateKey is false and the Public Key object is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first combined my cert.pem and privateKey.pem and regenerated the pfx. Then I updated how I got the cert from Azure Key Valut.

Old:

```
KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy certificate = await certificateClient.GetCertificateAsync(certName);
```

New:

```
var certificate = await certificateClient.DownloadCertificateAsync(certName);
```

Now the private key is with the ssl cert